# Some issues about Rob Conery's repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm, repository-pattern, poco

**Please read my update at the end of question after reading the answers:**

> I'm trying to apply repository pattern
>   as [Rob Conery's described](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/04/07/asp-net-mvc-mvc-storefront-part-2) on
>   [his blog](http://blog.wekeroad.com/category/mvc-storefront) under "*MVC Storefront*".
>   But I want to ask about some issues
>   that I had before I apply this design
>   pattern.
>
> Rob made his own "Model" and used some
>   ORM "LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework (EF)" to map his database to
>   Entities.
>
> Then he used custom Repositories which
>   gives `IQueryable<myModel>` and in
>   these repositories he made sort of
>   **Mapping or "Parsing" between ORM `Entities` and his `Model` classes.**
>
> What I'm asking here:
>
> **Is it possible to make custom mapping between ORM `Entities` and my
>   model "`classes`" and load just
>   properties that I want?** I hope
>   the point is clear.

***Update For POCO***

**

### This is what I decided after many of suggestions and many of tries:

**

*After all and with respect to Mr. Rob Conery's opinion I've got better solution as:*

1. I built my model as "`POCO`s" and put them in my "Models Layers" so they had nothing to do with the "edmx" file.
2. Built my repositories to deal with this "`POCO`" model dependent on "`DbContext`"
3. Then I created a "`ViewModels`" to get just the information that needed by view from those repositories.

So I do ***not* need to add one more layer** to be between "EF Models" and "My Model". I just twist my model a little and force EF to deal with it.

As I see this pattern is better than Rob Conery's one.

Comment: Are you concerned with loading all the data from a table or loading all the columns from a single row of a table?  In either case, there are ways to load just what you want regardless of the Repository pattern.

Comment: That's why God invented the view model and AutoMapper. You're not supposed to return everything off your model to your view... that's just poor design. You're talking about 2 different things here... you're talking about data access and showing data on a view. Those SHOULD be kept separate. The repository pattern is great for DI into your controller... I would highly recommend it because of the simplicity.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if you're using LINQ to SQL. All you need to do is use projection to pull out the data you want into an object of your choosing. You don't need all this decoration with interfaces and whatnot - if you use a model specific to a view (which it sounds like you need) - create a ViewModel class.

Let's call it ProductSummaryView:

```
public class ProductSummaryView{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public decimal Price {get;set;}
}
```

Now load it from the repository:

```
var products= from p in _repository.GetAllProducts
              where p.Price > 100
              select new ProductSummaryView {
                  Name=p.ProductName,
                  Price=p.Price

              }
```

This will pull all products where the price > 100 and return an IQueryable. In addition, since you're only asking for two columns, only two columns will be specified in the SQL call.

Comment: Thanks very much Mr.Rob for your answer. And just more curiosity this ViewModel class should be in my Model class library and use L2S directly to fill it not using my Repository. Am I right ??.  Thanks very much again

Comment: Your ViewModel should be with the UI bits - not the model. This is an "adaptive" pattern to help the web app cope with the model data - you want to keep it where it's used.

Answer (score 3):

Not a dodge to your question, but it's ultimately up to you to decide how your repository would work.

The high-level premise is that your controller would point to some repository interface, say **`IRepository<T> where T : IProduct`**. The implementation of which could do any number of things---load up your whole database from disk and store in memory and then parse LINQ expressions to return stuff. Or it could just return a fixed set of dummy data for testing purposes. Because you're banging away on an repository interface, then you could have any number of concrete implementations.

Now, if you're looking for a critique of Rob's specific implementation, I'm not sure that's germane to Stack Overflow.

Comment: An aside--re-reading your post, I'd strongly suggest you not follow a pattern where you load only subsets of your object's properties based upon context.  It's a fake lazy loading and it's extremely error prone as that object gets passed around to different contexts.  If you must, then consider a base and derived class, one w/ a smaller subset of properties while the other has the full details.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion and that what i were going to do but actually I'm trying to find something easier ;) So Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

While it's possible to populate part of an object based on a query of a subset of the columns for that object using a query (which has nothing to do with the repository pattern), that's not how things are "normally" done.

If you want to return a subset of an object, you generally create a new class with just that subset of properties.  This is often (in the MVC world view) referred to as a View Model class.  Then, you use a projection query to fill that new class.

You can do all of that whether you are using the repository pattern or not.  I would argue there is no conflicting overlap between the two concepts.

Comment: OK i made new class with just needed properties but I'll fill this class from my customized repository which will load all data from L2S classes and fill them to my Model Class then I'll get just the property i want. this what happens in Rob's Repository pattern.

But i i depend on L2S classes i could select just what i want but that will lead me to break my layers down.

Answer (score 2):

### DeferringTheLoad

Remember that IQueryable defers all the loading up to the last responsible moment. You probably won't have to load all the data using the LINQ operators to get the data you want. ; )

Respecting the dependency in domain classes in views, I will say NO. Use a ViewModel pattern for this. It's more maintainable; you could use [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper) to avoid the mapping problems, and they are very flexible in composite views scenarios : )

According to the new question...The answer is yes, you can. Just as Rob Conery says, use projection ; ):

```
var query = from p in DataContext.Persons}
select new Persons
{
  firstname = p.firstname,
  lastname = p.lastname
});
```