# Subsonic 3 : get only certain columns

Tags: serialization, subsonic3, json.net

I use : Subsonic 3, SQL Server 2008, Json.Net

Here is my problem :

I have a house table with id,lot number, address, location, ownerid and an owner table with id,name, description.

I'd like to get only the owner name and address of house where location is "San Francisco".

How can I do this with Subsonic?

My problem is I can only get a typed list or a datareader, I don't understand how to only get an array or a simple list.

What is the best solution? Create a custom class ? Create a View ? Anything else ?

My aim is to then serialize the data to send it back to my application, but serialization is seriously long because of the numerous relationships (My example here is simplified, there are indeed : house - owner - city - country etc.), whereas I need only 2 fields...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Some Issues about  Rob Conery's repository pattern ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272026/some-issues-about-rob-conerys-repository-pattern), rob provides the answer to exactly what you're asking for.

If the information is only going to be used in one place, maybe use a struct with two fields?